# How to display full-screen overlay from within iFrame?

Tags: html, css, overlay

In HTML, I have an iFrame on my screen which is only occupying a small portion of the screen ('World' in the example below).

From that iFrame, I want to create a full-screen div overlay, however the overlay is only covering the portion of the iFrame. How can I extend that div to really cover the full screen ?

Code Example.
main.htm:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table width=100% style='border:1px solid black;'>
    <tr><td style='border:1px solid black;' width=50%>Hello</td><td style='border:1px solid black;' width=50%>
        <iframe src=test2.htm>
        </iframe>
        </td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

test2.htm:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    .BigPhoto {
        display: block;
        z-index:100;
        background-color:red;
        position:fixed;
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class=BigPhoto>World</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Result (red is supposed to cover the full screen):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In short: you can't. The border of an Iframe is an absolute boundary for the objects inside.

What you could try is resizing the Iframe dynamically to full height and width through JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

OK, just found a way.
Via javascript, bring the div on the top layer:

```
 var MyDiv = document.getElementById('MyDiv');
 var topFrame=parent.document.getElementById('top');

 topFrame.insertBefore(MyDiv, parent.document.getElementById('wrap_all'));
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are doing here as you code does not state which div is where, but I highly doubt that this works. Especially when your frame content comes from another domain.

Comment: I actually tested it and it worked. I am using wordpress: The top dom structure is called 'top' and the first div in it is wrap_all. I 'simply' take the MyDiv which is burried in the iFrame, bring it above just before the wrap_all which covers the whole screen.